# How to use class based views for repeated forms

Tags: python, django

I'm not very familiar with cbvs and I was wondering if it is applicable in this example. I have several views in my django project that are extremely similar. They follow this pattern:

```
@login_required
@listing_ownership
def edit_listing_location(request, listing):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = EditLocationForm(request.POST, instance=listing)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('listings:edit_listing_details', args=listing.id))
    else:
        form = EditLocationForm(instance=listing)
    context = {'form': form, 'user': request.user, 'listing': listing}
    return render(request, 'listing/edit_listing_location.html', context)
```

Where the only thing changing in between them is the template name and the return url. Is this pattern something that CBV's could make the code shorter?

Thanks!

Comment: You could just translate that to a cbv that inherits from View, and then subclass it for each of the other views that you need. You may want to try using FormView or UpdateView as base class if they work for you. The code in the end will be less, like 3 lines per each new class.

Comment: You can use CBVs for this. The CBVs included in django already have a DetailView and ListView which do the same exact thing. Please go through the docs.

Answer (score 0):

The FormView does that exactly. It displays the unbound form in GET requests and in POST or PUT, it checks if the form is valid and then posts it. On success you can specify a redirect url also.

Here's a piece of code:

```
class CreateListing(FormView):
    template_name = 'listing/edit_listing_location.html'
    success_url = 'listing/edit_listing_details'
    form_class = ListingForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save()
```

Comment: How do I prepopulate the form?

Comment: Try: form = MyForm({'charfield1': 'foo', 'charfield2': 'bar'})